# Keycloak: custom user storage provider multiple getUserById calls during user login

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/bbalakriz/rhsso-custom-user-storage-jpa) to add custom user storage provider. While testing the integration, I noticed multiple `getUserById` method calls happening during user login:

```
15:01:07,809 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) getUserByUsername: bala
15:01:07,837 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) supportsCredentialType: true
15:01:07,837 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) supportsCredentialType: true
15:01:07,839 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) getUserById: f:1b171a2b-0d7f-42eb-9c93-89fd7c71347b:bala
15:01:07,851 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-3) WFLYEJB0487: Unexpected invocation state 0
15:01:07,852 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) supportsCredentialType: false
15:01:07,856 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) getUserById: f:1b171a2b-0d7f-42eb-9c93-89fd7c71347b:bala
15:01:08,313 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) getUserById: f:1b171a2b-0d7f-42eb-9c93-89fd7c71347b:bala
15:01:08,322 INFO  [com.redhat.custom.storage.user.CustomUserStorageProvider] (default task-3) getUserById: f:1b171a2b-0d7f-42eb-9c93-89fd7c71347b:bala
```

Can anyone explain me why that is happening?

Comment: In general it's ok. User model could be queried multiple time during different execution flows. You can put a breakpoint in your Storage Provider implementation so, you will be able to trace purposes of every call.

Comment: @solveMe, thanks for your answer. Will do that.

Comment: I found answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743197/5284890).